# Content Security Policy not working for Ionic serve

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

In my `index.html` I have a meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

When I run `ionic serve` (Ionic version is 1.6.1) I get following error:

> Refused to load the script
>   'http://localhost:35729/livereload.js?snipver=1' because it violates
>   the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'
>   'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' http://localhost:8100"

Does anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I noticed, you have set `script-src` to `self` which means the scripts will load from your domain only with same origin (host name).

Your port number changed when you run it on web server because it chooses randomly selected port to run the application. I do not have any knowledge about `Ionic` server but for `CSP`, i can conclude that.

In your case, `localhost:35729` and `localhost:8100` are obviously not the same so the policy header blocks the loading of the script.

To fix this, it is better to use the host name for your app. In addition, `CSP` works better if you send it through `HTTP response header` rather than in `meta` tag. Please let me know if you have any doubt.